# problems with IDE IJ Community vs IJ Ultimate

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

I create a Maven project with IJ Community Edition, and it's work with no errors. After I try to open this project with IJ Ultimate, but my progect(exercises) went to break up in both IDE.

```
Abnormal build process termination:
/home/viktoriya/.jdks/adopt-openjdk-1.8.0_292/bin/java -Xmx700m - 
Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.endorsed.dirs=\"\" Dexternal.project.config=/home/viktoriya/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.2/external_bui 
ld_system/aop.8b786682 -Dcompile.parallel=false -Drebuild.on.dependency.change=true - 
Djdt.compiler.useSingleThread=true -Daether.connector.resumeDownloads=false - 
Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier=-3134077656729915217 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 - 
Duser.language=it -Duser.country=IT -Didea.paths.selector=IntelliJIdea2021.2 - 
Didea.home.path=/snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/311 - 
Didea.config.path=/home/viktoriya/.config/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.2 - 
Didea.plugins.path=/home/viktoriya/.local/share/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.2 - 
Djps.log.dir=/home/viktoriya/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.2/log/build-log - 
Djps.fallback.jdk.home=/snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/311/jbr - 
Djps.fallback.jdk.version=11.0.11 -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true - 
Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/viktoriya/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.2/compile- 
server/aop_fceb3a58/_temp_ -Djps.backward.ref.index.builder=true - 
Dtmh.instrument.annotations=true -Dtmh.generate.line.numbers=true - 
Dkotlin.incremental.compilation=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation.js=true - 
Dkotlin.daemon.enabled -Dkotlin.daemon.client.alive.path=\"/tmp/kotlin-idea- 
12642686614178805058-is-running\" -classpath /snap/intellij-idea- 
ultimate/311/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar:/home/viktoriya/.jdks/adopt-openjdk- 
1.8.0_292/lib/tools.jar org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher /snap/intellij-idea- 
ultimate/311/lib/jps-model.jar:/snap/intellij-idea- 
ultimate/311/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-transport-file-1.3.3.jar:/snap/intellij- 
idea-ultimate/311/lib/forms_rt.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/311/lib/jna- 
platform.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/311/plugins/java/lib/jps- 
builders.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/311/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders- 
6.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/311/lib/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.jar:/snap/intellij- 
idea-ultimate/311/lib/slf4j.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/311/lib/protobuf-java- 
3.15.8.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/311/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver- 
connector-basic-1.3.3.jar:/snap/intellij-idea- 
ultimate/311/lib/idea_rt.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/311/plugins/java/lib/maven- 
resolver-transport-http-1.3.3.jar:/snap/intellij-idea- 
ultimate/311/lib/jna.jar:/snap/intellij-idea- 
ultimate/311/plugins/java/lib/javac2.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/311/lib/3rd- 
party.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/311/plugins/java/lib/jps-javac-extension- 
1.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/311/lib/util.jar:/snap/intellij-idea- 
ultimate/311/lib/annotations.jar:/snap/intellij-idea- 
ultimate/311/plugins/java/lib/aether-dependency-resolver.jar:/snap/intellij-idea- 
ultimate/311/lib/platform-api.jar:/snap/intellij-idea- 
ultimate/311/plugins/JavaEE/lib/jasper-v2-rt.jar:/snap/intellij-idea- 
ultimate/311/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-reflect.jar:/snap/intellij-idea- 
ultimate/311/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-plugin.jar:/snap/intellij-idea- 
ultimate/311/plugins/ant/lib/ant-jps.jar:/snap/intellij-idea- 
ultimate/311/plugins/uiDesigner/lib/jps/java-guiForms-jps.jar:/snap/intellij-idea- 
ultimate/311/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-jps.jar:/snap/intellij-idea- 
ultimate/311/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-common.jar:/snap/intellij-idea- 
ultimate/311/plugins/IntelliLang/lib/java-langInjection-jps.jar:/snap/intellij-idea- 
ultimate/311/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-jps.jar:/snap/intellij-idea- 
ultimate/311/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-constants-rt.jar:/snap/intellij-idea- 
ultimate/311/plugins/maven/lib/maven-jps.jar:/snap/intellij-idea- 
ultimate/311/plugins/gradle-java/lib/gradle-jps.jar:/snap/intellij-idea- 
ultimate/311/plugins/devkit/lib/devkit-jps.jar:/snap/intellij-idea- 
ultimate/311/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-jps.jar:/snap/intellij-idea- 
ultimate/311/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-common.jar:/snap/intellij-idea- 
ultimate/311/plugins/JavaEE/lib/javaee-jps.jar:/snap/intellij-idea- 
ultimate/311/plugins/webSphereIntegration/lib/jps/javaee-appServers-websphere- 
jps.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/311/plugins/weblogicIntegration/lib/jps/javaee- 
appServers-weblogic-jps.jar:/snap/intellij-idea- 
ultimate/311/plugins/JPA/lib/jps/javaee-jpa-jps.jar:/snap/intellij-idea- 
ultimate/311/plugins/Grails/lib/groovy-grails-jps.jar:/snap/intellij-idea- 
ultimate/311/plugins/Grails/lib/groovy-grails-compilerPatch.jar:/snap/intellij-idea- 
ultimate/311/plugins/Kotlin/lib/jps/kotlin-jps-plugin.jar:/snap/intellij-idea- 
ultimate/311/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-jps-common.jar:/snap/intellij-idea- 
ultimate/311/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-common.jar org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain 
 127.0.0.1 36431 07bedbac-3b45-46ae-985c-23aa3cfc7910 
 /home/viktoriya/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.2/compile-server
 /home/viktoriya/.jdks/adopt-openjdk-1.8.0_292/bin/java: 1: ��ELF: not found
 /home/viktoriya/.jdks/adopt-openjdk-1.8.0_292/bin/java: 2: ��: not found
 /home/viktoriya/.jdks/adopt-openjdk-1.8.0_292/bin/java: 3: ��: not found
 /home/viktoriya/.jdks/adopt-openjdk-1.8.0_292/bin/java: 4: ����: not found
 /home/viktoriya/.jdks/adopt-openjdk-1.8.0_292/bin/java: 5: ��: not found
 /home/viktoriya/.jdks/adopt-openjdk-1.8.0_292/bin/java: 6: ��: not found
 /home/viktoriya/.jdks/adopt-openjdk-1.8.0_292/bin/java: 7: TTT: not found
 /home/viktoriya/.jdks/adopt-openjdk-1.8.0_292/bin/java: 8: ��: not found
 /home/viktoriya/.jdks/adopt-openjdk-1.8.0_292/bin/java: 9: ��: not found
 /home/viktoriya/.jdks/adopt-openjdk-1.8.0_292/bin/java: 10: PP/lib64/ld-linux- 
 x86-64.so.2GNU: not found
 /home/viktoriya/.jdks/adopt-openjdk-1.8.0_292/bin/java: 16: Syntax error: ")" 
 unexpected`
```

So I try to open it again with IJ Community, but I's was also broked. I create a new one,identical, with the same classes and the same Maven dependecies with IJ Community, I change just the name progect, and it's work.
So my question is why IJ Utilmate broke my progect and how may I adjust it.
After I create a simple Maven progect with just an System.out.println("hello"); with Ij Ultimate, and I've got the same results like in my firs progect, so was broked with the same message about "Abnormal buiild process terminated".
So the problem it's not in my code, but with IJ Ultimate Ide. How may I fix it? Because I prefer work with Ultimate edition.
Thank you

Comment: `/home/viktoriya/.jdks/adopt-openjdk-1.8.0_292/bin/java` looks corrupted, try reinstalling the JDK or switch to a different JDK version.

Comment: @CrazyCoder thank you, it was truly a problem with jdk. Now the project it's work in the both ide

Comment: It seems like configured JDK is invalid